# Popup / tooltip animation with Dojo

Tags: javascript, animation, dojo

Is it possible to animate a popup in Dojo? or anyway... I need to animate a popup "ToolTip style" with custom content.

I've tried http://jsfiddle.net/QSmvW/7/

To get a `TooltipDialog` to open with an `"onClick"` event (and not with an hover), but I'm unable to animate the `"onShow"`

I've seen somekind of dialog with dojo.fx that can be animated, but it seems to be a 1.6 feature (and I'm using Dojo 1.4.1)

**Do I need to upgrade to achieve this?**

**Is it possible to animate a custom tooltip (triggered with a click)?**

What I want is something like this :

http://www.hotajax.org/tooltip/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to rewrite nearly entirely the [Popup.js](http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/browser/dojo/branches/1.4/dijit/_base/popup.js?rev=22888&order=name) (i used dojo 1.4) class in dojo to get another type of object that uses animations to show / unshow :|

Apparently that's the best solution to get this kind of object with dojo...